# I get a 500 error when I add 'madeForKids' parameter to 'youtube.liveBroadcasts.insert' API

Tags: youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have one question about how to use 'madeForKids' in 'youtube.liveBroadcasts.insert' API.

When I don't use this parameter, the user interface of youtube will pop up a window to let me choose wether it is made for kids. I don't want it to show this window. I want to set this value with API.
   But when I added this parameter, it will always response a 500 error.

My codes is based on JS as follows:

```
    this.youtube.liveBroadcasts.insert(
      {
        auth: this.oauth2Client,
        part: "snippet,contentDetails,status",
        resource: {
          snippet: {
            title: title,
            scheduledStartTime: scheduledStartTime
          },
          status: {
            madeForKids: "false",
            selfDeclaredMadeForKids: "false",
            lifeCycleStatus: "live",
            privacyStatus: "public"
          },
          contentDetails: {
            rojection: "360",
            monitorStream: {
              enableMonitorStream: false
            }
          }
        }
      },
      function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("The API:createLiveBroadCast returned an error: " + err);
          reject(new Error(err));
        } else {
          console.log(response);
          resolve(response);
        }
      }
    );
```

Additionally, I am using the latest googleapis: "^48.0.0".

Can anyone help me ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: make sure to add "```" to the end of your code block to close it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the status attribute in LiveBroadcast.
After you insert LiveBroadcast, you must update the video asset and set the status attributes there.  Use the LiveBroadcast.ID you just added.  You must reset the title and description at the same time or they will get set to null.

Like this:

```
       var videoRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Update(
            new Video {
                Id = "xxxxxx",
                Kind = "youtube#video",
                Snippet = new VideoSnippet
                {
                    Title = "updated title",
                    CategoryId = "28"
                },
                Status = new VideoStatus
                {
                    PrivacyStatus = "unlisted",
                    SelfDeclaredMadeForKids = false
                }
            },
            "snippet,status"
        );
        var videoResponse = videoRequest.Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling for [`liveBroadcasts.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert) endpoint, if wanting to designate the respective broadcast as *child-directed*, you shoudn't use the [`makeForKids`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#status.madeForKids) property, but [this one](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#status.selfDeclaredMadeForKids) instead:

> *status.selfDeclaredMadeForKids*: **boolean**
>
> In a liveBroadcasts.insert request, this property allows the channel owner to designate the broadcast as being child-directed. In a liveBroadcasts.list request, the property value is only returned if the channel owner authorized the API request.

See the [list of properties](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert#request-body) allowed to be used by this endpoint. It mentions `selfDeclaredMadeForKids` but not `madeForKids`!